# How to solve the integration?

Tags: integration

Solve the Integral :

$$\int_0^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x}dx, \text{ where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.}$$

Comment: What do you mean by "the greatest integer"?

Comment: You could use $\int e^{-x}dx=-\int d(e^{-x})$, though I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: @gregkow He means the floor function.

Comment: @Michael Hardy : thanks for editting

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: For sufficiently nicely convergent integrals,

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \int_{n}^{n + 1} f(x) dx$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** In other words,

$$\int_1^\infty e^{-x}dx+\int_2^\infty e^{-x}dx+\int_3^\infty e^{-x}dx+\dots$$

Comment: This is nice and clever; avoids a potentially troublesome sum. But it's not immediately clear how you obtained the expression (took me a few minutes), I would suggest a light explanation or some of the algebra.

Comment: @G.H.Faust I disagree.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this 
$$\int_0^{\infty}  \lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x}dx = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} (n)\int_{n}^{n + 1}  e^{-x}dx$$